# Dismissed/Closed Callback Method for STPopupController?

Tags: ios, uiviewcontroller

I am using this great STPopup:
http://cocoadocs.org/docsets/STPopup/1.2.0/Classes/STPopupController.html

```
- (void)showPopupWithTransitionStyle:(STPopupTransitionStyle)transitionStyle rootViewController:(UIViewController *)rootViewController
{
    STPopupController *popupController = [[STPopupController alloc] initWithRootViewController:rootViewController];
    popupController.cornerRadius = 4;

    popupController.transitionStyle = transitionStyle;
    [popupController presentInViewController:self];
    //[popupController dismissWithCompletion:^{NSLog(@"Dismissed!");}];

}

- (IBAction)btnClick:(id)sender {
    [self showPopupWithTransitionStyle:STPopupTransitionStyleSlideVertical rootViewController:[ad new]];
}
```

This is working fine so far, but i want to execute a code when popup is closed. How can i do this?

Thx!

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion the best solution.

```
- (void)didMoveToParentViewController:(UIViewController *)parent
{
    if (![parent isEqual:self.parentViewController]) {
         NSLog(@"Popup close!");
    }
}
```

But it only works with iOS5+

Answer (score -1):

Instead of

```
[popupController presentInViewController:self];
```

use following code,

```
 [popupController presentInViewController:self completion:^{
    NSLog(@"Dismissed!");
 //execute your code when popup is closed, here!
}];
```

EDIT:
you can use following method for executing code after dismissing the popup.

```
- (void)dismissWithCompletion:(void ( ^ ) ( void ))completion
```

Comment: this is only executing that `completion` code when the popup is finished  popping up. And *not when it is Closed by tapping on the Cross button.

Answer (score -1):

The viewWillDisappear&viewDidDisappear of the view controller, which is shown in popup controller, will be called when the popup controller is dismissed.